# How to find the duration of difference between two dates in java?

Tags: java, date-arithmetic

I have two objects of **DateTime**, which need to find the **duration of their difference**,

I have the following code but not sure how to continue it to get to the expected results as following:

**Example**:

```
      11/03/14 09:30:58
      11/03/14 09:33:43
      elapsed time is 02 minutes and 45 seconds
      -----------------------------------------------------
      11/03/14 09:30:58 
      11/03/15 09:30:58
      elapsed time is a day
      -----------------------------------------------------
      11/03/14 09:30:58 
      11/03/16 09:30:58
      elapsed time is two days
      -----------------------------------------------------
      11/03/14 09:30:58 
      11/03/16 09:35:58
      elapsed time is two days and 05 minutes
```

**Code**:

```
    String dateStart = "11/03/14 09:29:58";
    String dateStop = "11/03/14 09:33:43";

    Custom date format
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Get msec from each, and subtract.
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
    System.out.println("Time in seconds: " + diffSeconds + " seconds.");
    System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + diffMinutes + " minutes.");
    System.out.println("Time in hours: " + diffHours + " hours.");
```

Comment: Please have a look at Joda time, which has built in support for this.

Comment: whats wrong with you code, you just need some tweaks to achieve required output, let try it

Comment: First find the difference in hours , with the remainder find the difference in minutes and then the seconds !

Comment: You need to clarify what your problem is.  Some might assume you have trouble doing the calculations when it appears to me you are having trouble writing the logic for the output.

Comment: @Abu not sure how to do the same for date

Comment: @J888 divide by another 24x, there are 24 hours in a day.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot not sure how to do the same for date

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have provided different examples

Comment: @J888 You need a function which will give you the text for the number of days as words.  Do numbers really need to have a padded 0 at the start.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Well there are *usually* 24 hours in a day. Not always though, due to DST transitions. We'd need to know more about what these date/time values really represent - which time zone they started in.

Comment: @aquestion duplication means two questions which expects the same results, the expected output of this question is different with the one you provided.

Comment: Check this there are 22 answers hope you will solve the problem, after that simply use SimpleDateFormat to format accordingly.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Answer (score 73, accepted):

try the following

```
{
        Date dt2 = new DateAndTime().getCurrentDateTime();

        long diff = dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime();
        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
        int diffInDays = (int) ((dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        if (diffInDays > 1) {
            System.err.println("Difference in number of days (2) : " + diffInDays);
            return false;
        } else if (diffHours > 24) {

            System.err.println(">24");
            return false;
        } else if ((diffHours == 24) && (diffMinutes >= 1)) {
            System.err.println("minutes");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: This answer ignores time zones which define the beginning and ending of days. This answer ignores Daylight Saving Time and other anomalies that mean a day is not always 24 hours in length. See the correct answers that use either Joda-Time or java.time libraries.

Comment: As Basil has pointed out, this answer is incorrect.  It gives the wrong number of days if the end date occurs during daylight savings time but the start date does not.

Answer (score 227):

The date difference conversion could be handled in a better way using Java built-in class, [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html). It provides utility methods to do that:

```
Date startDate = // Set start date
Date endDate   = // Set end date

long duration  = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
long diffInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(duration);
```

Comment: Alternatively
 long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(duration,TimeUnit.MILLSECONDS);

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: I second that motion; This answer is the best.

Comment: No dependence on 3rd party library.

Comment: Hi first of all thank you so much for your short and nice answer, I am facing one problem on your solution like I have two date 06_12_2017_07_18_02_PM and another one is 06_12_2017_07_13_16_PM, I am getting 286 seconds
instead I should get only 46 seconds

Comment: Note that this solution will only calculate full seconds/minutes/hours etc without fraction since the returned value is a `long`. For instance if you calculate the minutes between `08:06:30` and `08:00:00` the result will be `6` and not `6.5`.

Comment: Best straight answer this is...and you can add one more answer `long diffInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(duration);`

Comment: OP needs the diff in days, hours and minutes. Where hours and minutes are not absolute, but the remainder. This solution is concise but does not provide the same answers.

Answer (score 50):

Use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library

```
DateTime startTime, endTime;
Period p = new Period(startTime, endTime);
long hours = p.getHours();
long minutes = p.getMinutes();
```

Joda Time has a concept of time Interval:

```
Interval interval = new Interval(oldTime, new Instant());
```

One more example
[Date Difference](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/DateDifferent.shtml)

One more [Link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/)

or with Java-8 (which integrated Joda-Time concepts)

```
Instant start, end;//
Duration dur = Duration.between(start, stop);
long hours = dur.toHours();
long minutes = dur.toMinutes();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Joda time is the way to go

Comment: The only safe way to handle properly timezones, daylight changes etc

Comment: Just a small typo: you meant "end" not "stop" in your 2nd line ("Duration dur = Duration.between(start, stop);").

Answer (score 13):

Here is how the problem can solved in Java 8 just like the answer by shamimz.

Source :  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(1960, Month.JANUARY, 1);

Period p = Period.between(birthday, today);
long p2 = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(birthday, today);

System.out.println("You are " + p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths() + " months, and " + p.getDays() + " days old. (" + p2 + " days total)");
```

The code produces output similar to the following:

```
You are 53 years, 4 months, and 29 days old. (19508 days total)
```

We have to use LocalDateTime http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html to get hour,minute,second differences.

Comment: It is so much like the Joda-Time way as answered by MayurB. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Your link to [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is old. Current URL is http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: LocalDate is not storing time and timezone. It keeps only day-month-year.  see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: This doesn't take the time into consideration. The OP's question had seconds, minutes, and hours.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a method like

```
public long getDaysBetweenDates(Date d1, Date d2){
return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());
}
```

This method will return the number of days between the 2 days.

Comment: Short answer. Solutions must be liks this.

Answer (score 7):

```
Date d2 = new Date();
Date d1 = new Date(1384831803875l);

long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
int diffInDays = (int) diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

System.out.println(diffInDays+"  days");
System.out.println(diffHours+"  Hour");
System.out.println(diffMinutes+"  min");
System.out.println(diffSeconds+"  sec");
```

Comment: Hi first of all thank you so much for your short and nice answer, I am facing one problem on your solution like I have two date 06_12_2017_07_18_02_PM and another one is 06_12_2017_07_13_16_PM, I am getting 286 seconds instead I should get only 46 seconds

Answer (score 6):

As Michael Borgwardt writes in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3491723/552116):

> ```
> int diffInDays = (int)( (newerDate.getTime() - olderDate.getTime()) 
>                  / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) )
> ```
>
> Note that this works with UTC dates, so the difference may be a day
>   off if you look at local dates. And getting it to work correctly with
>   local dates requires a completely different approach due to daylight
>   savings time.

Comment: Its not good idea to multiply these value manually. Rather use java TimeUnit class to do that.

Comment: What you say regarding local dates is not true. The getTime() method, according to API doc *Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.* If two numbers have the same unit, it is safe to add and subtract them.

Comment: Yes. It is safe but the code is not clean as the java provides standard way to handle this.

Comment: In addition to providing a link to an answer, you must clearly quote wording that you've copied from others.

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8, you can make of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html), and [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). Here is an example:

```
final String dateStart = "11/03/14 09:29:58";
final String dateStop = "11/03/14 09:33:43";

final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
        .appendLiteral('/')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
        .appendLiteral('/')
        .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 2, 2, 2000)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
        .appendLiteral(':')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
        .toFormatter();

final LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStart, formatter);
final LocalDateTime stop = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStop, formatter);

final Duration between = Duration.between(start, stop);

System.out.println(start);
System.out.println(stop);
System.out.println(formatter.format(start));
System.out.println(formatter.format(stop));
System.out.println(between);
System.out.println(between.get(ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
```

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me can try with this, hope it will be helpful . Let me know if any concern .

```
Date startDate = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); //set your start time
Date endDate = java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); // set  your end time

long duration = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();


long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
long diffInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(duration);

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Diff"
        + duration + diffInDays + diffInHours + diffInMinutes + diffInSeconds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); **// Toast message for android .**

System.out.println("Diff" + duration + diffInDays + diffInHours + diffInMinutes + diffInSeconds); **// Print console message for Java .**
```

Comment: long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);

Answer (score 3):

with reference to shamim's answer update here is a method that does the task without using any third party library. Just copy the method and use

```
public static String getDurationTimeStamp(String date) {

        String timeDifference = "";

        //date formatter as per the coder need
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        //parse the string date-ti
        // me to Date object
        Date startDate = null;
        try {
            startDate = sdf.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //end date will be the current system time to calculate the lapse time difference
        //if needed, coder can add end date to whatever date
        Date endDate = new Date();

        System.out.println(startDate);
        System.out.println(endDate);

        //get the time difference in milliseconds
        long duration = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

        //now we calculate the differences in different time units
        //this long value will be the total time difference in each unit
        //i.e; total difference in seconds, total difference in minutes etc...
        long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
        long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
        long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
        long diffInDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(duration);

        //now we create the time stamps depending on the value of each unit that we get
        //as we do not have the unit in years,
        //we will see if the days difference is more that 365 days, as 365 days = 1 year
        if (diffInDays > 365) {
            //we get the year in integer not in float
            //ex- 791/365 = 2.167 in float but it will be 2 years in int
            int year = (int) (diffInDays / 365);
            timeDifference = year + " years ago";
            System.out.println(year + " years ago");
        }
        //if days are not enough to create year then get the days
        else if (diffInDays > 1) {
            timeDifference = diffInDays + " days ago";
            System.out.println(diffInDays + " days ago");
        }
        //if days value<1 then get the hours
        else if (diffInHours > 1) {
            timeDifference = diffInHours + " hours ago";
            System.out.println(diffInHours + " hours ago");
        }
        //if hours value<1 then get the minutes
        else if (diffInMinutes > 1) {
            timeDifference = diffInMinutes + " minutes ago";
            System.out.println(diffInMinutes + " minutes ago");
        }
        //if minutes value<1 then get the seconds
        else if (diffInSeconds > 1) {
            timeDifference = diffInSeconds + " seconds ago";
            System.out.println(diffInSeconds + " seconds ago");
        }

        return timeDifference;
// that's all. Happy Coding :)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the code:

```
        String date1 = "07/15/2013";
        String time1 = "11:00:01";
        String date2 = "07/16/2013";
        String time2 = "22:15:10";
        String format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date fromDate = sdf.parse(date1 + " " + time1);
        Date toDate = sdf.parse(date2 + " " + time2);

        long diff = toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime();
        String dateFormat="duration: ";
        int diffDays = (int) (diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        if(diffDays>0){
            dateFormat+=diffDays+" day ";
        }
        diff -= diffDays * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        int diffhours = (int) (diff / (60 * 60 * 1000));
        if(diffhours>0){
            dateFormat+=diffhours+" hour ";
        }
        diff -= diffhours * (60 * 60 * 1000);

        int diffmin = (int) (diff / (60 * 1000));
        if(diffmin>0){
            dateFormat+=diffmin+" min ";
        }
        diff -= diffmin * (60 * 1000);

        int diffsec = (int) (diff / (1000));
        if(diffsec>0){
            dateFormat+=diffsec+" sec";
        }
        System.out.println(dateFormat);
```

and the out is:

```
duration: 1 day 11 hour 15 min 9 sec
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the similar problem using a simple method recently.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(utc);
        Date until = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
        Date since = calendar.getTime();
        long durationInSeconds  = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(until.getTime() - since.getTime());

        long SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE = 60;
        long MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR = 60;
        long HOURS_IN_A_DAY = 24;
        long DAYS_IN_A_MONTH = 30;
        long MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR = 12;

        long sec = (durationInSeconds >= SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE) ? durationInSeconds % SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE : durationInSeconds;
        long min = (durationInSeconds /= SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE) >= MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR ? durationInSeconds%MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR : durationInSeconds;
        long hrs = (durationInSeconds /= MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR) >= HOURS_IN_A_DAY ? durationInSeconds % HOURS_IN_A_DAY : durationInSeconds;
        long days = (durationInSeconds /= HOURS_IN_A_DAY) >= DAYS_IN_A_MONTH ? durationInSeconds % DAYS_IN_A_MONTH : durationInSeconds;
        long months = (durationInSeconds /=DAYS_IN_A_MONTH) >= MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR ? durationInSeconds % MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR : durationInSeconds;
        long years = (durationInSeconds /= MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR);

        String duration = getDuration(sec,min,hrs,days,months,years);
        System.out.println(duration);
    }
    private static String getDuration(long secs, long mins, long hrs, long days, long months, long years) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String EMPTY_STRING = "";
        sb.append(years > 0 ? years + (years > 1 ? " years " : " year "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append(months > 0 ? months + (months > 1 ? " months " : " month "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append(days > 0 ? days + (days > 1 ? " days " : " day "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append(hrs > 0 ? hrs + (hrs > 1 ? " hours " : " hour "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append(mins > 0 ? mins + (mins > 1 ? " mins " : " min "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append(secs > 0 ? secs + (secs > 1 ? " secs " : " secs "): EMPTY_STRING);
        sb.append("ago");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

And as expected it prints: `7 days ago`.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time.Duration

I still didn’t feel any of the answers was quite up to date and to the point. So here is the modern answer using `Duration` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API (the answers by MayurB and mkobit mention the same class, but none of them correctly converts to days, hours, minutes and minutes as asked).

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    
    String dateStart = "11/03/14 09:29:58";
    String dateStop = "11/03/14 09:33:43";

    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    ZonedDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStart, formatter).atZone(zone);
    ZonedDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStop, formatter).atZone(zone);
    
    Duration diff = Duration.between(startDateTime, endDateTime);
    if (diff.isZero()) {
        System.out.println("0 minutes");
    } else {
        long days = diff.toDays();
        if (days != 0) {
            System.out.print("" + days + " days ");
            diff = diff.minusDays(days);
        }
        long hours = diff.toHours();
        if (hours != 0) {
            System.out.print("" + hours + " hours ");
            diff = diff.minusHours(hours);
        }
        long minutes = diff.toMinutes();
        if (minutes != 0) {
            System.out.print("" + minutes + " minutes ");
            diff = diff.minusMinutes(minutes);
        }
        long seconds = diff.getSeconds();
        if (seconds != 0) {
            System.out.print("" + seconds + " seconds ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output from this example snippet is:

> 3 minutes 45 seconds

Note that `Duration` always counts a day as 24 hours. If you want to treat time anomalies like summer time transistions differently, solutions inlcude (1) use `ChronoUnit.DAYS` (2) Use `Period` (3) `Use` LocalDateTime`instead of`ZonedDateTime` (may be considered a hack).

The code above works with Java 8 and with ThreeTen Backport, that backport of java.time to Java 6 and 7. From Java 9 it may be possible to write it a bit more nicely using the methods `toHoursPart`, `toMinutesPart` and `toSecondsPart` added there.

I will elaborate the explanations further one of the days when I get time, maybe not until next week.

Answer (score 0):

This is a program I wrote, which gets the number of days between 2 dates(no time here).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter starting date separated by dots: ");
  String inp1 = s.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter ending date separated by dots: ");
  String inp2 = s.nextLine();
  int[] nodim = {
   0,
   31,
   28,
   31,
   30,
   31,
   30,
   31,
   31,
   30,
   31,
   30,
   31
  };
  String[] inpArr1 = split(inp1);
  String[] inpArr2 = split(inp2);
  int d1 = Integer.parseInt(inpArr1[0]);
  int m1 = Integer.parseInt(inpArr1[1]);
  int y1 = Integer.parseInt(inpArr1[2]);
  int d2 = Integer.parseInt(inpArr2[0]);
  int m2 = Integer.parseInt(inpArr2[1]);
  int y2 = Integer.parseInt(inpArr2[2]);
  if (y1 % 4 == 0) nodim[2] = 29;
  int diff = m1 == m2 && y1 == y2 ? d2 - (d1 - 1) : (nodim[m1] - (d1 - 1));
  int mm1 = m1 + 1, mm2 = m2 - 1, yy1 = y1, yy2 = y2;
  for (; yy1 <= yy2; yy1++, mm1 = 1) {
   mm2 = yy1 == yy2 ? (m2 - 1) : 12;
   if (yy1 % 4 == 0) nodim[2] = 29;
   else nodim[2] = 28;
   if (mm2 == 0) {
    mm2 = 12;
    yy2 = yy2 - 1;
   }
   for (; mm1 <= mm2 && yy1 <= yy2; mm1++) diff = diff + nodim[mm1];
  }
  System.out.print("No. of days from " + inp1 + " to " + inp2 + " is " + diff);
 }
 public static String[] split(String s) {
  String[] retval = {
   "",
   "",
   ""
  };
  s = s + ".";
  s = s + " ";
  for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
   retval[i] = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("."));
   s = s.substring((s.indexOf(".") + 1), s.length());
  }
  return retval;
 }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/HRsjTtUf

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the difference between two DateTime using this**

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.now();
DateTime endDate = DateTime.now();
Days daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);
System.out.println(daysBetween.toStandardSeconds());
```

Answer (score 0):

**The below code will give the difference between two DateTime (Will work in Java 8 and above)**

```
private long countDaysBetween(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime enddate)
{
    if(startDate == null || enddate == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such a date");
    }
    
    long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, enddate);
    
    return daysBetween;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants a string with all of them together, this function can be used.

```java
String getTimeDifference(long duration) {
    StringBuilder timeRemaining = new StringBuilder();

    long days = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(duration);
    if (days >= 1) {
        timeRemaining.append(days).append((days == 1) ? " day " : " days ");
    }

    duration -= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days);
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration);
    if (hours >= 1) {
        timeRemaining.append(hours).append((hours == 1) ? " hour " : " hours ");
    }

    duration -= TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
    if (minutes >= 1) {
        timeRemaining.append(minutes).append((hours == 1) ? " minute " : " minutes ");
    }
        
    return timeRemaining.toString().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.time.Duration;
 import java.time.Instant;

public class Timedifference {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // Check if all time stamps are 
 within 45 seconds of other

    Instant[] timestamps = new 
 Instant[8];
    timestamps[0] = Instant.now();
    timestamps[1] = 
 timestamps[0].plusSeconds(20);
    timestamps[2] = 
  timestamps[1].plusSeconds(30);
    timestamps[3] = 
   timestamps[2].plusSeconds(10);
    timestamps[4] = 
  timestamps[3].plusSeconds(5);
    timestamps[5] = 
 timestamps[4].plusSeconds(15);
    timestamps[6] = 
  timestamps[5].plusSeconds(20);
    timestamps[7] = 
 timestamps[6].plusSeconds(10);

    // Check if all timestamps are 
  within 45 seconds of the first 
  timestamp
    Duration maxDuration = 
 Duration.ofSeconds(45);
    boolean areWithin45Seconds = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < 
  timestamps.length; i++) {
        Duration duration = 
  Duration.between(timestamps[0], 
 timestamps[i]);
        if 
 (Math.abs(duration.getSeconds()) > 
   maxDuration.getSeconds()) {
            areWithin45Seconds = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (areWithin45Seconds) {
        System.out.println("the given
 timestamps are within 45 seconds of 
  each other.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("the given 
  Not all timestamps are within 45 
   seconds of each other.");
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   // calculating the difference b/w startDate and endDate
        String startDate = "01-01-2016";
        String endDate = simpleDateFormat.format(currentDate);

        date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(startDate);
        date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(endDate);

        long getDiff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

        // using TimeUnit class from java.util.concurrent package
        long getDaysDiff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(getDiff);
```

[How to calculate difference between two dates in Java](http://www.websparrow.org/tutorials/java/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-dates-in-java)