# Comparing two time for a fixed difference in java

Tags: java, android

### I have my code

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date curDate = new Date();
String finalCurTime=format.format(curDate).substring(11, 19);

Date gpsLastDate = new Date(gpslastKnownLocation.getTime());
String gpsFinalLastTime=format.format(gpsLastDate).substring(11, 19);
```

---

### How can i compare to below Logic

- Compare `finalCurTime` & `gpsFinalLastTime`

---

```
If(If finalCurTime is more than three hours of gpsFinalLastTime)
{
// Do something-1
}else{
// Do something-2
}
```

Comment: Why are you looking at the *string* representations?

Comment: why are you not comparing date object directly using compareTo() ?

Comment: @Jon Skeet ... I taught this would be easier. How can I use date objects directly for my use case

Comment: @HareshChhelana ...How can I use date objects directly for my use case, are there any existing Stackoverflow answers for this kind of scenario ?

Comment: Look at `Date.getTime()`, which will return the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. Subtracting integers tends to be easier than subtracting strings :)

Comment: create a custom funtion in which you pass date as argument and it return the hours 

then compare hours it's the best way to do that

Comment: @Jon Skeet .... OK, any method where I can specify the threshold(difference) along with `Date.getTime()`.

Comment: You don't. You perform normal arithmetic. Pretend we weren't talking about dates and times - if you had a `Person` API with an `int getSalary()` method, and you wanted to check whether one person's salary was (say) at least 5000 more than another's, what would you do? Figure that out, then apply it to the date/time domain.

Comment: @JonSkeet ... Got it .... so the result of `Date.getTime()` is shown in milliseconds so i just have to see the difference for three hours(in milli seconds). Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java checkout this it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Date.getTime() to get the time in milliseconds.

```
// If the difference in milliseconds is larger than 3 hours in milliseconds
if (curDate.getTime() - gpsLastDate.getTime() > 10800000) {
    // Do something-1
} else {
    // Do something-2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar calendarobj = Calendar.getInstance();
calendarobj.setTime(gpsLastDate);
int hour = calendarobj.get(Calendar.HOUR);
if(hour>3)
    System.out.println("greater");
```