# Difference between two Dates in HH:MM:SS - Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, iso

I currently have two Calendar instances that are set to specific dates and times, they are:

```
Fri 14th March 2015 - 09:00:00 GMT
Mon 17th March 2015 - 10:30:15 GMT
```

What i'd like is a way to get the difference in days, hours, minutes and seconds, in a Day:HH:MM:SS format. Note the dates can be in different timezones. So in this example, the answer should be:

```
3:1:30:15
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances) or  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java) could help you ;)

Comment: I would use Joda Time, and its Interval class: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_interval.html

Comment: How do you want to handle daylight saving time changes? Is this a diff between "local" dates and times (where 2am to 2am is always deemed "1 day") or a difference between points in time (where 2am to 2am could be 25 hours or 23 hours, as well as 24 hours)?

Comment: The dates could be in different timezones. The first date is always Europe/London, but the second one could be any timezone. It is a difference between points in time, so essentially a year is also involved in the difference.

Comment: You could first normalize both global timestamps to the same timezone (for ex. Europe/London) and then calculate the duration between the associated local timestamp representations. Are you open for other libraries? I ask because this is very hard in old JDK-classes like `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: Convert both dates into java.time.ZonedDateTime. Then use the static method to calculate the duration:
`Duration d = Duration.between(dt1, dt2);`
and format the duration accordingly.