# Find Diffrence between two dates with time zones java/android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to find the difference between two java dates with time zone.
Time zone is GMT.Sever sends the time in this format **2015-04-08 11:17:53 -0400**. I want to find the difference (in minutes)between server sent date format and current android system time.

I am finding the difference like this.c_date is the server date format(2015-04-08 11:17:53 -0400)

```
public static long getDiffrenceBetween(String c_date,String old_date) {
    System.out.println("Cuttent Time   :::"+c_date);
    System.out.println("Saved/Old Time :::"+old_date);

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    long min_In_Minutes=0;

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(c_date);
        d2 = format.parse(old_date);

        // in milliseconds
        long diff = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
        min_In_Minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);

        System.out.println("Diff in Minutes :::"+min_In_Minutes);

        long diffSeconds = diff / (1000 % 60);
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        System.out.println(diffDays + " days, ");
        System.out.println(diffHours + " hours, ");
        System.out.println(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
        System.out.println(diffSeconds + " seconds.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return min_In_Minutes;
}
```

but this is giving negative value in minutes. what is wrong in this method. Please suggest.

Hoping that can find a solution here.
Thanks in advance,
sharath.

Comment: use http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. can you please post a sample of code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java

Comment: I have tried this.updated my question.Please check.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Android you obiosly cant use Java 8 and its new time api so I would reccomand using Joda-time - an external library for time.

Example for between calculation:

```
Seconds.between(startDate, endDate);
```

More details here: [joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score 0):

GMT is the time anywhere in the world. GMT time code shows the difference between GMT and your local time. So theoretically ,

if your local time code is +/- "GMT 5.00" 
difference between GMT and your local time  = 5 * 60 minutes