# How to get day,hours,minutes to reach a certain date

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, datepicker, android-date

I need to get **Day** **Hours** **Minutes** to reach certain date 
example :

> Date = "14-08-2015 16:38:28"

```
Current_Date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
```

and to reach that `Date` the result will be 
**2 Days and 1 hour and 30 minutes**

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please detail more et put your code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple searching on google I got

```
    String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";
    String dateStop = "01/15/2012 10:31:48";

    //HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

        //in milliseconds
        long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

        long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
        long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

        System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
        System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
        System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
        System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

see below links

1. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/
2. [How to find the duration of difference between two dates in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java)
3. [Calculate date/time difference in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java)

Comment: Thank u , that's what i'm looking for .
can i just ask one question :
why i got -1 on my question  !!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

There are plenty of constants in Calendar for everything you need. Edit: [Calendar class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)