# How to find the duration of difference between two dates

Tags: java, date

I have two dates, eg. 1989-3-21, 2016-3-21  and I want to find the duration of difference between those dates. For this I am trying the following code but I am unable to get the duration of difference in dates.

```
public String getTimeDiff(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo) {
        String diff = "";
        long timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime());
        diff = String.format("%d hour(s) %d min(s)", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff)));
        return diff;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the duration of difference between two dates in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java)

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1989-3-21" (at offset 5) this exception coming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your dates like so before calling `public String getTimeDiff(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo)`:

```
    Date dateOne=null,dateTwo=null;
    try {
        dateOne = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" ).parse("2016-3-21");
        dateTwo =  new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" ).parse("1989-3-21");
    } 
    catch (ParseException ex) {     
    }
    System.out.println( getTimeDiff(dateOne,dateTwo));



    public String getTimeDiff(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo) {
        String diff = "";
        long timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime());
        diff = String.format("%d date(s) ", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timeDiff));
        return diff;
    }
```

Since your Dates aren't in their default format you will have to use a SimpleDateFormat to explicitly declare the format of your Dates.

Comment: wait let me try ur logic

Comment: But i have to get difference in number of years not in hours

Comment: Check my edit, since you want date difference you also have to make some changes in your function.

Answer (score 0):

From  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java)

```
    long diff = dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime();
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
    int diffInDays = (int) ((dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

Comment: wait let me try ur logic

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This

```
try {
            /// String CurrentDate=  "10/6/2016";
            /// String PrviousDate=  "10/7/2015";
            Date date1 = null;
            Date date2 = null;
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            date1 = df.parse(CurrentDate);
            date2 = df.parse(PrviousDate);
            long diff = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);


            System.out.println(diffDays);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception " + e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the difference and and call the method;
  **long diff = dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime();**

```
public static String toHumanReadableTime(long diff) {
        Long hour = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        diff= diff% (1000 * 60 * 60);
        Long minutes = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        diff= diff% (1000 * 60);
        Long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        diff= diff% 1000;
        Long milisec = diff;

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        if (hour != null && hour > 0) {
            buffer.append(hour).append(" Hour ");
        }
        if (minutes != null && minutes > 0) {
            buffer.append(minutes).append(" Minute ");
        }
        buffer.append(seconds).append(" Second ");

        buffer.append(milisec).append(" Millisecond  ");

        return buffer.toString();
    }
```