# Determine number of hours in a day using java.time

Tags: java, dst, java-time

I want to know the number of hours in a day when the DST (daylight saving time, summer time) is begins and ends.

Am willing to use `java.time`. Zone ID is `Europe/London`. The main intention is:

- when DST begins in the spring, we will have 23 hours in one day because clocks are turned forward
- conversely when DST ends, we will have 25 hours in one day.

I have an epoch value from which I should find the number of hours. How is it possible?

Comment: The answer is 23 when switching to DST and 25 when switching back. What's the remaining question here?

Comment: I have a epoch value from which i should find the number of hours. How is it possible?

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130669/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates ?

Comment: I never saw anything unclear about this question. I hope my edits helped those who did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
    long epochMillis = 1_540_700_000_000L;
    LocalDate date = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMillis)
            .atZone(zone)
            .toLocalDate();
    int hoursInDay = (int) ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(
            date.atStartOfDay(zone),
            date.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(zone));
    System.out.println(date + " is " + hoursInDay + " hours");
```

I didn’t choose the milliseconds since the epoch at random. In this case the output is:

> 2018-10-28 is 25 hours

Transition to standard time will happen on the last Sunday in October, this year on October 28.

The Australia/Lord_Howe time zone uses 30-minute DST transitions, so in that time zone the day would be either 23.5 hours or 24.5 hours, which in the above will be truncated to 23 and 24. But for London you should be OK until those crazy British politicians decide to do someting similar. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this. It really helped. :)

Comment: Using a `LocalDate(Time)` is probably an easier way to specify the date so you know it is on a DST change date.

Comment: @OleV.V. ah right. It might just be clearer to state "// this is 2018/10/28 <some time> UTC", or just say "...", rather than using a magic number.

Comment: It was always my plan to do something similar once I got a chance to try my own code, @AndyTurner. Thanks for inspiring the wording I ended up with.