# Day difference coming wrong

Tags: java, date

We have to do some security check for which we are getting some date from some part of our code and then we are calculating the difference in days

```
String userDate = EncryptUtil.getInstance().decrypt(Constants.USER_DATE);
String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(calendar.getTime());

long startTime = new Date(userDate).getTime();
long presentTime = new Date(currentDate).getTime();
long diffTime = presentTime - startTime;
long diffDays = diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

The `userDate` value is coming `03/06/2017` and `currentDate` is `07/06/2017`, both are correct, but when I'm calculating day difference (`diffDays`) it is giving a difference of **122**, where it should be actually **4**. I don't understand why? Can anybody help.

Comment: This looks _very_ dodgy to me `EncryptUtil.getInstance().decrypt`. In any case, **don't** use `Date` with the `String` constructor. In fact **don't** use the old API at all. Use a [`DateTimeFormatter `](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) then calculate a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). This code is awful.

Comment: @Boris the Spider can you please tell me from which package should I import DateTimeFormatter

Comment: I think Joda time is the way to go, please if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java

Comment: @sanojmathew can we please stop blanket recommending Joda time! The Java 8 Date/Time API is based on JodaTime and there are very few circumstances where such recommendation are now helpful. Oh if only comments had downvotes...

Comment: Whatever you do, don't convert milliseconds into days by dividing by `(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)`.  You'll get an error of one day when your date range spans the start of daylight savings time.  Remember, that if you're in a zone that uses daylight savings, there's a 23-hour day and a 25-hour day every year; and that makes a real difference to the result of this calculation.  You _must_ rely on one of the date-based libraries for this calculation - you _will_ get it wrong if you do it yourself.

Comment: From [the Joda-Time homepage](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/): “Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on the constructor of `java.util.Date` that takes a string. It's deprecated, so you should not be using it anyway. Parse the string using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
long startTime = fmt.parse(userDate).getTime();
```

Also, what you are doing with `currentDate` is an unnecessarily complicated and roundabout way to get the timestamp in milliseconds from `calendar`. You could just do this:

```
long presentTime = calendar.getTime().getTime();
```

No need for the variable `currentDate`.

Better yet would be to use the Java 8 date and time API (package `java.time`) instead of the old `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` classes.

Comment: thats right I can get current date from Calendar, but what about the other String date? How will I calculate the time for that

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran Parse the string into a `Date` object by calling `parse()` on a `SimpleDateFormat`. When you have a `Date` object, call `getTime()` on it to get the timestamp in milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

### Avoid the use the of the old `Date` API.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    LocalDate userDate = LocalDate.parse("03/06/2017", formatter);
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.parse("07/06/2017", formatter);

    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(userDate, currentDate);

    System.out.printf("%s days have passed%n", days);
}
```

---

Your actual issue is that you are assuming that `Date` parses `ddMMyyyy` which is not correct, that's the European date format rather than then US one.

From the [JavaDoc for `Date.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse-java.lang.String-) (which is used by the **Deprecated**(!!) `String` constructor):

> If the number is followed by a slash, it is regarded as a month (it is decreased by 1 to produce a number in the range 0 to 11), unless a month has already been recognized, in which case it is regarded as a day of the month.

i.e. it tries to parse a month first, then a day.

Comment: but I can't import DateTimeFormatter, LocalDate, ChronoUnit as well, we are using JDK 6.0

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran then you're not on Java 8. You probably should be - public updates for Java 7 ended a long time ago! But feel free to go with [Jesper's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44405764/2071828) for people using horribly out of date versions of Java.

Comment: sorry, but its not my place for suggestions, this is all what we are given. Thanks any ways

Comment: Yes, you can import the classes in Java 6, but it requires you to know how. Get [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and import the classes from the `org.threeten.bp` package (with subpackage `format`) (that’s Threeten for JSR-310).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your date is parsed not as ddMMyyyy, but as MMddyyyy format. That's why difference in days give you ~4 months, instead of 4 days.

You can stop using Deprecated API (new Date(String) is deprecated since Java 1.1) and start using fresh java time classes https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html