# Calculating the time difference between two times in Java

Tags: java, date, timedelta, localtime

```
    String time1 = br.readLine();
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date d1 = sdf.parse(time1);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        String time2 = br.readLine();
        Date d2 = sdf.parse(time2);
        long diffMs = d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
        System.out.println(diffMs/(1000*60*60));
```

Input:

```
time1 = 23:05:38
time2 = 12:36:07
```

Output should be **10** but it’s giving **22**.

Comment: `hh` is for 12-hour format, `HH` for 24-hour. I suspect that is your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the duration of difference between two dates in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java)

Comment: Just as a side note, use LocalTime and Duration it will be much easier.

Comment: @Deb, I consider that more than a side note, it’s the sound solution to the problem. The modern classes usually don’t let you get away with using `hh` instead of `HH` for parsing, so will prevent the problem from appearing in the first place. I consider this much better than trying to solve it afterward.

Comment: Nowadays you shouldn't use `Date` anymore. Instead use the new date/time API of Java inside the package `java.time`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Well, the java.time-API will not tolerate the pattern "hh:mm:ss" in parsing but tolerates it in printing!

Comment: True, @MenoHochschild. Frankly, it would be unreasonably strict to forbid it in formatting.

Comment: @OleV.V. About formatting in my time lib, I have forbidden such patterns on pattern level but allowed on builder level (where everyone hopefully sees the problem when looking at the field names). Pattern symbols are confusing so many people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I am assuming that the calculation takes place in a time zone without summer time (DST) and other anomalies, or at least on dates where there is no transition.

I left out the reading from the `BufferedReader` since you already seem to be handling this fine.

```
    String time1 = "23:05:38";
    LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.parse(time1);
    String time2 = "12:36:07";
    LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.parse(time2);
    Duration diff = Duration.between(t2, t1);
    System.out.println(diff.toHours());
```

This prints the expected

> 10

As you can see, I am following Deb’s suggestion in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876974/calculating-time-difference-between-two-time-stamp-in-java#comment80701395_46876974): using the [modern Java date and timeAPI known as JSR-310 or `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). This automatically solves your problem since `LocalTime` parses your times on the 24 hour clock without any explicit formatter and therefore without the opportunity to use the wrong case in a format pattern string.

That’s right, I agree with d.j.brown that the lowercase `hh` in your pattern is the culprit. Your times were interpreted as 23:05:38 AM, which is nonsense, but the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` just takes that to mean 11:05:38 PM, that is 23:05:38 on a 24 hour clock, that is what you had expected. IMHO it’s quite nasty to let you get away with such a bug without telling you. You were fortunate to have a time that started with “12”, for 12:36:07 AM means 0:36:07 on a 24 hour clock, so this time you got a wrong result and were made aware something was wrong. Otherwise your bug would have gone unnoticed, maybe for a long time. This long story to carry a morale: stay far away from `SimpleDateFormat`.

**Question: Can I use the modern API with my Java version?**

If using at least Java **6**, you can.

- In Java 8 and later the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get [the ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of the new classes (that’s ThreeTen for JSR-310, where the modern API was first defined).
- On Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP, and I think that there’s a wonderful explanation in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).