# how to calculate difference in time which has format TimeDuration

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to calculate difference between times required to perform specific tasks. For example,

```
Date startpipeline = new Date()
// ...task 1...
Date stoppipeline = new Date()
TimeDuration task1 = TimeCategory.minus( stoppipeline, startpipeline )
print "time taken by task1 is " + task1
```

By doing above I am getting proper out as `5 mins, 23 secs` etc. Similarly

```
Date startpipeline2 = new Date()
// ...task2...
Date stoppipeline2 = new Date()
TimeDuration task2 = TimeCategory.minus( stoppipeline2, startpipeline2 )
print "time taken by task2 is " + task2
```

By doing above I am getting proper out as `2 mins, 23 secs` etc.

But for some requirement i need to calculate difference between both the task I tried doing

```
TimeDuration diffbetween2task = TimeCategory.minus( task1, task2 )
```

but it gives an error. It expects task1 and task2 as date format. Can someone please help?

Comment: TimeCategory.minus has two different implementations: static Date minus​(Date date, BaseDuration duration)  
static TimeDuration minus​(Date lhs, Date rhs), you are using TimeDuration one, take a look at the docs: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html#minus(java.util.Date,groovy.time.BaseDuration)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the duration of difference between two dates in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use just `task1 - task2`

that's because the class TimeDuration has method [`minus`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/time/TimeDuration.html#minus(groovy.time.Duration)).

```groovy
import groovy.time.*

Date startpipeline = new Date()
Thread.sleep(1234)
Date stoppipeline = new Date()
TimeDuration task1 = TimeCategory.minus( stoppipeline, startpipeline )
println "time taken by task1 is " +task1


startpipeline = new Date()
Thread.sleep(2345)
stoppipeline = new Date()
TimeDuration task2 = TimeCategory.minus( stoppipeline, startpipeline )
println "time taken by task2 is " +task2


TimeDuration diff = task2-task1
println "diff " +diff
```

output:

```
time taken by task1 is 1.235 seconds
time taken by task2 is 2.345 seconds
diff 1.110 seconds
```

Comment: thanks @daggett .....didnt know this simple it was...thanks a lot