# How to convert Duration to seconds?

Tags: java

```
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 9, 2, 14, 17, 25, 135);
    LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 9, 2, 14, 19, 59, 965);
    Duration duration = Duration.between(start, end);
```

I need to get result in this format : `2:34.830`.

Minutes and nanoseconds  - no problem :

```
    System.out.println(duration.toMinutes());
    System.out.println(duration.toNanos());
```

but how can I gain seconds - 34 seconds from this example?

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940200/how-to-find-the-duration-of-difference-between-two-dates-in-java

Comment: Did you read [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a duration in java? (e.g format H:MM:SS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266825/how-to-format-a-duration-in-java-e-g-format-hmmss)

Comment: You can do with `duration.getSeconds() `

Comment: @Shafiul, no, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: In actual fact, `duration.toMinutes()` and `duration.toNanos()` also doesn't do what OP expects. See the linked javadoc for more details, and read it carefully.

Comment: I strongly suspect that `toMinutesPart()`, `toSecondsPart()` and `toNanosPart()` are the desired methods here.

Comment: @PankajSinghal Yes!

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is the following:

```
System.out.println(duration.getSeconds()%60);
```

Alternatively,

```
System.out.println(duration.getSeconds() - duration.toMinutes()*60);
```

From Java 9, there is a dedicated method for this [toSecondsPart()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toSecondsPart--):

```
System.out.println(duration.toSecondsPart());
```

Answer (score 0):

With some math, you can get it like expected.

```
        long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
        long seconds = duration.getSeconds() % 60;
        long nanoSeconds = duration.toNanos() % 1000_000_000L;
        System.out.println(String.format("%d:%d.%d", minutes, seconds, nanoSeconds));
```

Output:

```
2:34.830
```

Edit:
After @M. Prokhorov's comment, extending it for hours also, similarly:

```
    long hours = duration.toHours();
    long minutes = duration.toMinutes() % 60;
```

And format it like:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d:%d:%d.%d", hours, minutes, seconds, nanoSeconds));
```

Output:

```
0:2:34.830
```

Comment: That **if** OP is OK with duration of several hundred minutes in this printout.

Comment: true, assuming from the example that his interest is in minute precision.